# How to create multi-relational edge-list from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
 from itertools import * 
 from pandas as pd
 d = {'col1': ['a', 'b','c','d','a','b','d'], 'col2': ['XX','XX','XY','XX','YY','YY','XY']}
 df_rel = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
 df_rel
       col1 col2
    0   a   XX
    1   b   XX
    2   c   XY
    3   d   XX
    4   a   YY
    5   b   YY
    6   d   XY
```

The unique nodes are:

```
uniq_nodes = df_rel['col1'].unique()
uniq_nodes
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object)
```

For each `Relationship` the source (Src) and destination (Dst) can be generated:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=list(combinations(uniq_nodes, 2)), 
    columns=['Src', 'Dst'])
df1
  Src   Dst
0   a   b
1   a   c
2   a   d
3   b   c
4   b   d
5   c   d
```

I need the new dataframe `newdf` based on the shared elements in `col2` of `df_rel`. The `Relationship` column comes from the `col2`. Thus the desire dataframe with edgelist will be:

```
newdf

   Src  Dst Relationship
0   a   b   XX
1   a   b   YY
2   a   d   XX
3   c   d   XY
```

Is there any fastest way to achieve this? The original dataframe has 30,000 rows.

Comment: why Src is a in row 0 and row 2?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to do here. Where does Src and Des come from? Are they derived from "Relationship" column and in that case how?

Comment: Clarification is provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I took this approach. It works but still not very fast for the large dataframe.

```
 from itertools import * 
 from pandas as pd
 d = {'col1': ['a', 'b','c','d','a','b','d'], 'col2': ['XX','XX','XY','XX','YY','YY','XY']}
 df_rel = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
 df_rel
       col1 col2
    0   a   XX
    1   b   XX
    2   c   XY
    3   d   XX
    4   a   YY
    5   b   YY
    6   d   XY   

uniq_nodes = df_rel['col1'].unique()
uniq_nodes
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
            data=list(combinations(unique_nodes, 2)),
            columns=['Src', 'Dst'])
     
filter1 = df_rel['col1'].isin(df1['Src'])
src_df = df_rel[filter1]
src_df.rename(columns={'col1':'Src'}, inplace=True)
filter2 = df_rel['col1'].isin(df1['Dst'])
dst_df = df_rel[filter2]
dst_df.rename(columns={'col1':'Dst'}, inplace=True)
new_df = pd.merge(src_df,dst_df, on = "col2",how="inner")
print ("after removing the duplicates")
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates()
print(new_df.shape)
print ("after removing self loop")
new_df = new_df[new_df['Src'] != new_df['Dst']]
new_df = new_df[new_df['Src'] != new_df['Dst']]
new_df.rename(columns={'col2':'Relationship'}, inplace=True)
print(new_df.shape)
print (new_df)
           Src Relationship Dst
        0   a           XX   b
        1   a           XX   d
        3   b           XX   d
        5   c           XY   d
        6   a           YY   b
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your `df1` rows, and find the rows from `df_rel` that matches the `df1['Src']` and `df1['Dst']` columns. Once you have the `df1['col2']` values of `Src` and `Dst`, compare them and if they match create a row in `newdf`. Try this - check if it performs for large datasets

Data setup (same as yours):

```
d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'd'], 'col2': ['XX', 'XX', 'XY', 'XX', 'YY', 'YY', 'XY']}
df_rel = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

uniq_nodes = df_rel['col1'].unique()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=list(combinations(uniq_nodes, 2)),  columns=['Src', 'Dst'])
```

Code:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Src','Dst','Relationship'])
for i,  row in df1.iterrows():
    src = (df_rel[df_rel['col1'] == row['Src']]['col2']).to_list()
    dst = (df_rel[df_rel['col1'] == row['Dst']]['col2']).to_list()
    for x in src:
        if x in dst:
            newdf = newdf.append(pd.Series({'Src': row['Src'], 'Dst': row['Dst'], 'Relationship': x}),
                                 ignore_index=True, sort=False)

print(newdf)
```

Result:

```
  Src Dst Relationship
0   a   b           XX
1   a   b           YY
2   a   d           XX
3   b   d           XX
4   c   d           XY
```